# Return a promise that resolves after all pending promises have finished

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function, `save`, that can be called multiple times and makes an AJAX call to our server. While the function is still saving, I want to show an indicator on the page that will go away after ALL save requests have finished. I want the promise returned from `save` to resolve once ALL request have finished. I can't simply use `Promise.all`, because more requests might come in before all save requests have finished. For example:

```
let pending_promises = [];

function addPromise(index, time = 5000) {
  console.log('adding promise ' + index);
  var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, time);
  });

  pending_promises.push(promise);

  return promise
    .then(() => {
      console.log('done with promise ' + index);
      return Promise.all(pending_promises);
    })
    .then(() => {
      pending_promises = [];
    });
}

addPromise(1, 5000).then(() => {
  console.log('DONE WITH THEM ALL');
})

addPromise(2, 1000);
addPromise(3, 6000);

window.setTimeout(() => {
  addPromise(4, 2000);
}, 5500);
```

This is close to working, but the console.log saying "DONE WITH THEM ALL" will print before the 4th promise resolves. Can anyone provide some help?

Comment: Is it important to know the result of previous save requests? I have a feeling that if you are performing a save, then you should only ever be monitoring one request - the most recent one.

Comment: FYI, if you're using jQuery for your Ajax calls, jQuery already has this capability built in (to tell you when the count of pending ajax calls goes to non-zero and goes to zero - precisely for the use case you describe.

Comment: The results of the previous don't really matter. I would have already attached a `then` to the first request, I can't really cancel those `thens` from firiing

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to keep an array of promises.  You can instead, just keep track of the tail promise.  Whenever a promise resolves, check if it's still the tail.  If it is still the tail, then there are no more promises in the chain so everything is done.  Here's one way to code that:

```js
let promiseTail = Promise.resolve();
let opInFlight = false;

// simulated ajax call
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, v), t);
    });
}

function someAsyncCall(index, t) {
    if (!opInFlight) {
        console.log("----------------------------");
        console.log("Starting chain of operations");
        opInFlight = true;
        // show spinner here
    }

    // insert your actual ajax call here
    console.log('starting async operation ' + index);
    let p = delay(t).then(function(result) {
        console.log('done with async operation ' + index);
        return result;
    });

    let thisPromise;

    function complete() {
        // if our promise was also the promiseTail, 
        //   then everything that was in flight is now done
        if (promiseTail === thisPromise) {
            console.log("All done with chain of operations");
            console.log("---------------------------------");
            opInFlight = false;
            // hide spinner here
        }
        return p;
    }

    // now hook this promise onto the chain
    // and remember it's value locally so it can be compared later
    thisPromise = promiseTail = promiseTail.then(complete, complete);

    // return this specific promise so a caller can know when this specific
    // async operation is done
    return p;
}

// testing...

someAsyncCall(1, 5000);
someAsyncCall(2, 1000);
someAsyncCall(3, 6000);
someAsyncCall(4, 2000).then(function(result4) {
    console.log("async operation 4 .then() handler called");
});

// now start one at little later to make sure it makes it into the chain too
setTimeout(function() {
    someAsyncCall(5, 1000);
}, 2500);

// now start some after the above have all finished to see if another chain works
// and we can detect the second completion

setTimeout(function() {
    someAsyncCall(10, 2000);
    someAsyncCall(11, 1000);
}, 7000);
```

Code Explanation:

1. Keep track of two pieces of state.  The last promise we added to the chain and a boolean that tells us when nothing was previously in flight.
2. Whenever we start a new operation, we added it onto the end of a promise chain and set the tail of the chain to that new promise.
3. We add a `.then()` handler onto every promise we put on the chain and anytime we see a `.then()` fire and the end of the chain is still what it was after we added ours to the chain, then there must be nothing else in the chain so the chain is now empty.  We notify the chain is empty and then reset the `opInFlight` flag (this allows us to later detect when we're starting a new chain).
4. This design assumes that a rejected promise should just keep the chain processing normally (not aborting the chain) so that ajax call should just be counted as completed, even if it failed (for purposes of this accounting).

Notes: A nice clean design would create an eventEmitter object and emit several events:

1. "ajaxFlagBegin" - when it went from no ajax operations in flight to an ajax operation in flight.
2. "ajaxFlagEnd" - when it goes back to no ajax operations in flight
3. "ajaxStart" - when any ajax operations starts
4. "ajaxEnd" - when any ajax operation completes

Then, any caller could listen for whatever events they were most interested in.

Answer (score 0):

If the result of the previous calls don't really matter, then you don't need to worry about them.

My pseudo code for this case (and I run across it often) is usually something like this:

```
var myRequest;

function save() {
   //it's important that you abort the previous ajax call
   //before you show the spinner
   if(myRequest) { 
        myRequest.abort(); 
    }

   showSpinner();
   myRequest = //your ajax call

   //hide the spinner regardless of the result of the request
   myRequest.then(
     function() { hideSpinner(); },
     function() { hideSpinner(); }
   );

   //return the request
   return myRequest;
};

save().then(function() { alert('done!'); })
```

Comment: This seems to make an assumption that the 2nd ajax call never finishes before the 1st ajax call or that any subsequent ajax call can never finsh before a prior one.  I don't think that's really what is intended by the design question posed here and it's certainly not the general case of tracking "in flight" ajax calls so you can know when they are all done.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was basing my ideas on the comment from the OP that said `The results of the previous don't really matter` implying that a subsequent call to save renders any previous call to save irrelevant. It is not an assumption that the 2nd ajax call never finishes before the first one when the creation of a second one forces the first one to be cancelled immediately. I felt the problem the OP was encountering was different than the problem they asked to solve (as is often the case). Instead of tracking all the ajax calls, only ever make one at a time.